# Weird crash in the debugger

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on an app that is accessing an array of structs. This is in Xcode 14.3/Swift 5.

I got a crash in a loop and after examining the variables involved, I don't understand.

Here is the reported crash:

```
if serverConfig.serverURL == self.appDelegate.serverConfigurations[index].serverURL
```

The crash is "`Thread 142: Fatal error: Index out of range`" at the line above.

However, given that:

```
(lldb) po self.appDelegate.serverConfigurations.count
5
```

and:

```
(lldb) po index
2
```

How can I get a crash that the index is out of range?

To answer some questions, the serverConfigurations property array is built when the AppDelegate instance receives `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`. A dictionary is retrieved from the UserDefaults and is used to build the ServerConfiguration instances:

```
if let savedConfigurations = userDefaults.array(forKey: CONFIGURATION_KEY) {
        var index = 0;
        for item in savedConfigurations {
            let dictionaryConfig = item as! Dictionary<String, String>
            let serverConfig = ServerConfiguration.init(serverURL: String.init(dictionaryConfig[SERVER_URL_KEY]!) ,
                regionName:String.init(dictionaryConfig[REGION_NAME_KEY]!),
                isRefreshing: false,
                index: index,
                networkFailures: 0,
                lowFPSWarnings: 0)
            serverConfigurations.append(serverConfig)
            index += 1
            let serverStatus = ServerStatus.init(serverURL: dictionaryConfig[SERVER_URL_KEY],
                sim: nil,
                regionName: dictionaryConfig[REGION_NAME_KEY],
                fps: nil,
                timeDilation: nil,
                uniqueVisitors: nil,
                regionStatus: "Status: Unknown",
                restarts: nil,
                lastRestart: nil,
                lastUpdate: Date.distantFuture,
                statusUnknown: true,
                shownError: false)
            self.serverStatus.append(serverStatus)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is created `self.appDelegate.serverConfigurations`? Async? At start? Can you reproduce the crash?

Comment: If `appDelegate` is `AppDelegate` then accessing it from "Thread 142" is not a good idea... Generally try to avoid putting random non-UI related things in AppDelegate. Instead, either pass them around, or store them somewhere, or have your own singleton to keep them (because you are using singleton anyway, but a singleton that is not built to keep your custom stuff)

Comment: Many collections (Dictionaries, ArraySlice, ...) have indices that aren't consequtive numbers from `0` to `count-1`. What is `self.appDelegate.serverConfigurations.incides`?

Comment: I added the code to my question to show how the serverConfigurations array is built.
The `appDelegate` property of the class where the crash occurs is created like this:
`self.appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate`. I don't believe that this is causing the crash.